# How do I support emojis in internet explorer?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, internet-explorer, web, emoji

I'm developing a chatbot in node.js+react.js, and I need to support internet explorer 11+. The chatbot uses emojis, such as and ‍ , copied from https://getemoji.com/.
In chrome, ff, edge and safari, they look great, with the exception that sometimes a woman symbol appears after the ‍emoji. In internet explorer all the emojis are black-white - they look boring, and most of them don't work. 
Do you guys know a good polyfill, so all the emojis look nice?